# How to access DOM from AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to submit a form from controller function in AngularJS. I need to do this without using jQuery because the target site
gives me a cross domain error when I use jQuery. I need to just post the form. Is it possible to do from controller without using jQuery?

I tried to use $element service but it seems to be jquery way of doing it and it is not really going to the target url.
Thank you for any suggestions.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="@Model.Settings["URL"]" ng-controller="FormCtrl as fctrl">
</form>

setControllers.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$element', 'DataService',
      function ($scope, $state, $element, service) {

          var fctrl = this;

          function init() {
            $element.find('#myForm').submit();
          };

          init();
      }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can totally do

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
};
```

but neither my solution, nor your approach are very angular-ish. You should probably go for some sort of directive.

Answer (score 0):

Well. The angular way of submitting a form is by using `ng-submit`. Here's an example of how you can achieve it, in its simplest form, pun intended:

`html`

```
<html ng-app="FormModule">
    <section ng-controller="formController as form">
        <form ng-submit="form.submit()">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input ng-model="form.data.name" placeholder="Insert your name" />
            <button type="submit">Submit My Name To The Server</button>
        </form>
    </section>
</html>
```

`javascript`

```
angular
    .module('FormModule', [])
    .controller('formController', formCtrl);

formCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']; // or whatever injection

function formCtrl($scope) {
    var form = this;
    form.data = {}; // ng-model form.data.name will be available in this
    form.submit = submitTheForm;

    function submitTheForm() {
        $.post('url', form.data); // or whatever HTTP service you're using
    }
}
```

Anyway, to help you understand and write better Angular code, here's how I learned writing better, and it is reflected in the code above

1. [John Papa Angular 1.x Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y001)
2. [`ngSubmit` Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)